# Alternate HTML Styling in Bootstrap Horizontal Form

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some forms which mostly consist of input controls, but there are times when the horizontal form has a variant like the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <span class="col-md-3 control-label">Features</span>
   <div class="col-md-9">
     <span>This is not available.</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Or sometimes I have multiple controls:

```
<span class="col-md-3 control-label">Payment</span>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <input value="2" name="CustomerPaymentOption" type="radio">
  <span>Credit Card</span>
</div>
```

The label content doesn't quite line up at the same level as the control-label.  I've tried to mimic the css class for form-control to get span content to line up, but it never quite worked out so well in my scenarios.  Any recommendations on getting the content to line up?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print a static text you could use a static form control (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static).

If you want to use multiple checkboxes and radio buttons, you can also use what bootstrap provoides. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls.

Would you like to have something like this? http://www.bootply.com/ztbj1dCJrP

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple add class to the div (here my-label)

```
<span class="col-md-3 control-label">Payment</span>
<div class="col-md-9 my-label">
  <input value="2" name="CustomerPaymentOption" type="radio">
  <span>Credit Card</span>
</div>
```

and css

```
.my-label{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/a4n4nc1r/

for multiple http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/a4n4nc1r/2/